# .NET Sessions with React Cross Origin

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, session, fetch

I'm currently working on putting together my first React application, and I'm using fetch in order to communicate with my API which is currently being developed using the .net webapi. I am running into a bit of a wall however with getting my session variables on the .net server to work properly. Currently I'm running the react application separately locally and using the url of my .net server in order to make a request to the API server. Both of which are on the same machine despite using separate ports. The request is going through, but when i try to make a follow up request to get the current user information, it is not pull any information. I have looked, and it seems no cookies are being stored locally in the browser, so I'm assuming this is the issue. The code for my fetch looks something like this:

```
let url = "http://localhost:50405";
let requestObject = {
    mode: 'cors',
    credentials: 'include'
}
fetch(url + '/api/currentuser/get', requestObject).then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
});
```

However, res is null even after the session has been set. 
Also, on the server end, I have the following in my config file in order to allow for the cross-site request:

```
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://localhost:3000" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
```

I figured I would see if there's something obvious I am missing here.

Comment: Update: I have figured out that you can call the api via the dev server with a proxy: https://www.ibm.com/blogs/bluemix/2017/06/react-web-express-api-development-production/ However, it seems like my state still isn't sticking.

Comment: Did you set/add a proxy setting in your package.json and point it to your service address?